# Not getting expected output in Maya python scripting for gui

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am making a gui in maya using python script but i am not getting the expected output.

I want to display that `Submit Button` outside the Tab layout but i am doing something wrong .Can anyone correct me  ?

End of the first text field i want to add a button `choose` like added in expected output .

**code:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Make a new window

window = cmds.window( title="Render", iconName='BTD', widthHeight=
(400,500),titleBar=True,minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True)

form = cmds.formLayout()
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=10, innerMarginHeight=10)
cmds.formLayout(form,edit=True,attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 
0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )
child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='1')
cmds.button(label='2')
cmds.button(label='3')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.setParent( '..' )


child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1,columnOffset = 
(1,'left',10))
#cmds.text("Output Directory",width = 50,height=50,font = "boldLabelFont")
cmds.text("Output Directory",width=200, height=50,font="boldLabelFont", 
align='left')
name = cmds.textField(w = 300,h = 20)

cmds.text("Notify on job completion",width = 200,height=50,font = 
"boldLabelFont",align='left')
name = cmds.textField(w = 370,h = 20)




cmds.setParent( '..' )


child3 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='7')


cmds.button(label='8')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'General'), (child2, 
'Advanced'),(child3, 'Job Software')) )
cmds.setParent( '..' )


#cmds.setParent( '..' )   
cmds.button("Submit Job",width=100, height=50, align='right') 

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not using setParent command, it is too confusing for me,
I've corrected you problem by adding parent flag in :  `form and cmds.button("Submit Job....)"`
Most of the time im using column and row layout only

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Make a new window

window = cmds.window( title="Render", iconName='BTD', widthHeight=
(400,500),titleBar=True,minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True)

columnMain = cmds.columnLayout() # <<================================
form = cmds.formLayout(p=columnMain)
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=10, innerMarginHeight=10)
cmds.formLayout(form,edit=True,attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 
0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )
child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='1')
cmds.button(label='2')
cmds.button(label='3')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.setParent( '..' )


child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1,columnOffset = 
(1,'left',10))
#cmds.text("Output Directory",width = 50,height=50,font = "boldLabelFont")
cmds.text("Output Directory",width=200, height=50,font="boldLabelFont", 
align='left')
name = cmds.textField(w = 300,h = 20)

cmds.text("Notify on job completion",width = 200,height=50,font = 
"boldLabelFont",align='left')
name = cmds.textField(w = 370,h = 20)




cmds.setParent( '..' )


child3 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='7')


cmds.button(label='8')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'General'), (child2, 
'Advanced'),(child3, 'Job Software')) )
cmds.setParent( '..' )


#cmds.setParent( '..' )   
cmds.button("Submit Job",width=100, height=50, align='right', p=columnMain) # <<================================

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

## EDIT -----

Here is example of how many layout, I would use : row/colum (note that the red rectangle is the tab widget)

[image]

## EDIT 2 -----

here a code example :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Make a new window

window = cmds.window( title="Render", iconName='BTD', widthHeight=(400,500),titleBar=True,minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )

# 1.0
columnMain = cmds.columnLayout() # the cyan rectangle

# 1.1 : First WIDGET : Conductor refresh - light green

conductorLayout = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=columnMain)
cmds.button(label='image', width=350, p=conductorLayout)
cmds.button(label='refresh', p=conductorLayout)


#1.2 : Second WIDGET : tab widget - in red
form = cmds.formLayout(p=columnMain)
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5, p=form)

#     1.2.1 : first tab widget - blue color
child1 = cmds.columnLayout(p=tabs)
#         1.2.1.2 : the green one with image picker
cmds.button(p=child1)
pickpath = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=child1)
name = cmds.textField(w = 370,h = 20, p=pickpath)
cmds.button( label='Submit Job',width=130,align='right', p=pickpath)
cmds.button(p=child1)

#     1.2.2 : second tab widget - blue Color

child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2,p=tabs)
cmds.button(p=child2)
cmds.button(p=child2)


cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'One'),(child2, 'Two')))

#1.3 Pink
submit_widget = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=columnMain)
cmds.checkBox(label='Scout Job', p=submit_widget)
cmds.button( label='Submit Job',width=130,align='right', p=submit_widget)
cmds.showWindow()
```

Comment: can you please explain this code using comment ? I am new and really confused who is parent of whom and thanks for the answer

Comment: i've posted an example