# How to align Button to right in maya python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I want to align button to the right and create checkbox to the left.
I want to display button and checkbox in one line .Thank you

**Code:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.window( width=200 )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=False )
cmds.button( label='Submit Job',width=130,align='right')
cmds.checkBox(label='Scout Job')
cmds.showWindow()
```

**Output**
[image]

**Expected output**
[image]

Comment: Yeah, nice! Why didn't you made your pictures even less on even bigger canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered you on your previous question but you have to think your layouts :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.window( width=200 )
main = cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=False )
submit_widget = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=main)
cmds.checkBox(label='Scout Job', p=submit_widget)
cmds.button( label='Submit Job',width=130,align='right', p=submit_widget)
cmds.showWindow()
```

## EDIT : here were the layouts highlighted from

[Not getting expected output in Maya python scripting for gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940276/not-getting-expected-output-in-maya-python-scripting-for-gui/47942528#47942528)
[image]