# Is there a way to make this (see picture) UI in Maya with python?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, maya

[(click here for image) The UI I want to make with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkOhb.jpg)

Is there a way to make this UI in Maya with python?
I've tried a couple methods.
But can't get the 'Info' button under and close to the 'fullscreen' button.
Any tips or methods that can help me.
(I would realy like to just give in pixel positions for the images.
But can't find a way to make this happen.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to do in `PySide`, which also ships with Maya.

You shouldn't want to set the position by pixels because, trust me, it'll be a huge hassle if you ever need to modify it. It also wouldn't resize with the window properly if you hard-code your interface. Instead you need to use nested layouts:

```
verticalLayout
  horizontalLayout
    button
    verticalLayout
      fullScreenButton
      infoButton
  .. do the same as above for other 2 main buttons
```

An example would look something like this:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)

        # The width of the buttons on the side.
        side_width = 30

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BAKE ANIMATION", parent=self)
        self.button_1.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding) # Make it stretchable vertically and horizontally.
        self.full_screen_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("[  ]", parent=self)
        self.full_screen_1.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding) # Make it stretchable only vertically.
        self.full_screen_1.setFixedWidth(side_width) # Give it a fixed width.
        self.info_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("i", parent=self)
        self.info_1.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.info_1.setFixedWidth(side_width)

        # Vertical layout for fullscreen and info buttons.
        self.side_layout_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.side_layout_1.addWidget(self.full_screen_1)
        self.side_layout_1.addWidget(self.info_1)

        # Horizontal layout for main button and previous vertical layout.
        self.sub_layout_1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.sub_layout_1.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.sub_layout_1.addLayout(self.side_layout_1)

        # Do the same for the 2nd section.
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("CONVERT TO\nSPECIAL KEYFRAME", parent=self)
        self.button_2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.full_screen_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("[  ]", parent=self)
        self.full_screen_2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.full_screen_2.setFixedWidth(side_width)
        self.info_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("i", parent=self)
        self.info_2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.info_2.setFixedWidth(side_width)

        self.side_layout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.side_layout_2.addWidget(self.full_screen_2)
        self.side_layout_2.addWidget(self.info_2)

        self.sub_layout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.sub_layout_2.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.sub_layout_2.addLayout(self.side_layout_2)

        # Do the same for the 3rd section.
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("MAKE\nBREAKDOWN POSE", parent=self)
        self.button_3.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.full_screen_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("[  ]", parent=self)
        self.full_screen_3.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.full_screen_3.setFixedWidth(side_width)
        self.info_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("i", parent=self)
        self.info_3.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.info_3.setFixedWidth(side_width)

        self.side_layout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.side_layout_3.addWidget(self.full_screen_3)
        self.side_layout_3.addWidget(self.info_3)

        self.sub_layout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.sub_layout_3.addWidget(self.button_3)
        self.sub_layout_3.addLayout(self.side_layout_3)

        # Add all sub layouts to a vertical layout.
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(2) # Reduce spacing to make it look more like your image.
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.sub_layout_1)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.sub_layout_2)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.sub_layout_3)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)


win = Window()
win.show()
```

[image: The result]

The code could be less long winded using loops or a function to create a "row section", but I hope that gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowLayout
         -> rowLayout
               -> button
               -> columnLayout -> button
                               -> button
```

This is the layout for one of your widget the button with two other one

if you want a similar topic where i've described this more in depth :
[Not getting expected output in Maya python scripting for gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940276/not-getting-expected-output-in-maya-python-scripting-for-gui/47942528#47942528)