# How do I reposition maya UI window elements?

Tags: python, maya

I've created this window, but the alignment of everything is just off. I don't know if its something to change in cmds.columnLayout or in the controls themselves, but can anyone help to explain how to position the UI elements?
Here is my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random

def createWindow(*args):
    global windowRandomizer
    global transMaxVal
    global transMinVal
    global rotateMaxVal
    global rotateMinVal
    global scaleMaxVal
    global scaleMinVal

    windowName = "Position Randomizer"
    
    windowRandomizer = cmds.window(t = windowName, mnb = False, mxb = False, s = True)
    cmds.columnLayout(rs = 5)
    
    transMaxVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Translate Max:", nf = 3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    transMinVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Translate Min:", nf =3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    
    cmds.separator(hr = True, style = "single", h = 5)
    
    rotateMaxVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Rotate Max:", nf =3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    rotateMinVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Rotate Min:", nf =3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    
    cmds.separator(hr = True, style = "single")
    
    scaleMaxVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Scale Max:", nf =3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    scaleMinVal = cmds.floatFieldGrp(l = "Scale Min:", nf =3, pre = 3, v1 = 0.000, v2 = 0.000, v3 = 0.000)
    
    cmds.separator(hr = True, style = "single")
    
    cmds.button(l = "Randomize", al = "center", c = executeScript)
    
    cmds.showWindow(windowRandomizer)
    
def executeScript(*args):
    pass
    
try: #On first run, will crash because windowRandomizer doesnt exist yet
    if (cmds.window(windowRandomizer, exists=True)):
        cmds.deleteUI(windowRandomizer, window=True)
except:
    pass

createWindow() #Call Function
```

[image: Window when code is run]
I'm not very code savvy so this might seem very basic and unoptimized, but it works for my purposes. The obvious issue is that the button is in the bottom left corner and the floatFieldGrps will have this empty space next to it. Even removing the button, the floatFieldGrps will still have that empty space. I've tried to change the width of the controls but that doesn't affect its positioning or the empty space to the left.

Comment: you should use columnLayout and rowLayout to parent your different widgets, it might help you

Comment: here is a similar question where I try to highlight the importance of layout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940276/not-getting-expected-output-in-maya-python-scripting-for-gui/47942528#47942528